# What's the difference between Passive Causative and just Passive Voice?

Tags: difference, verbs, passive-voice

In a clause with passive voice, the grammatical subject expresses the theme or patient of the main verb – that is, the person or thing that undergoes the action or has its state changed.
-My homework is done

The passive form of causative is used when the focus is on the thing instead of the person. When you combine them together, you are essentially saying someone caused something to be done .
-I have my homework done.
Does the difference lie in the performance of an action?

Comment: Neither of those sentences include passive or causitive. They're both *past participle adjectives*, unless "*My homework is done*" means "someone does my homework (every day)", and "*I have my homework done*" means to get someone else to do your homework for you, which I don't believe is the intent. If those are you intent, you should make that clear

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is not technically passive.

It is causative.

> I had X done.

The subject is “I,” and the subject performed the implied action. You can express the meaning as follows

> I made the arrangements that caused X to be done.

**However**, you are correct that a passive meaning applies to the doing of X

> I had Tom do my homework

is not passive at all. I made the arrangements; Tom did the work.

> I had my homework done

is active in part and passive in part. I made the arrangements, but who did the work is ignored.